# Bootstrap span'ы row почему то стоят друг под другом. Как это исправить?

Tags: bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">...</div>
<div class="span6">...</div>
<div class="span3">...</div>
</div>
```

Вот кладу такой код. Внутрь помещаю текст, для наглядности. 
CSS задаю так:

```
.span3 {
background-color: gray;
height: 300px;
}

.span6 {
background-color: gray;
height: 300px;
}
```

Width не задаю. Думаю для этого я и пользуюсь бутстрапом.

Вывод получаю так:

```
ABCDE

ABCDE

ABCDE
```

именно с отступом. Что то тут не то. Но что? Роюсь в документации, но там все нормально. Рылся и в книжке, но там тоже все норм - столбцами. А у меня строки какие то!

Comment: у bootstrap вроде свои делители на 6х и 3х? У 3ей версии `.col-md-6` и `.col-md-3`

Comment: @IVsevolod все! Село на места все! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Либо бутстрап старый, либо надо его собственные колоночные классы использовать.

Ну и как альтернативный вариант, добавить в твои классы `float:left`.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/45095)

Comment: @xaja, `float:left` - это ответ. После этого они встанут как надо.

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте добавить в стиль каждого span

```
display: inline-block
```

Comment: ничего. Все так же